# Client for SSL Secure Server in java - "No X509TrustManager implementation available exception" occurred

Tags: java, security, ssl

I have developed a server using SSL security in Java(Self Signed Certificate). Now developing the client of it but not sure I am doing it correct or not. 
I'm using self signed certificate for server and client.

Steps Followed: 
 1. Create server.jks using keytool 
 2. develop the server code
 3. run the server on a computer
 4. test the server using Cygwin on different and it passed the SSL test
 5. Create the client.jks on different computer 
 6. develop client program to access the server 
 7. Getting Exception

My Server Code:

```
    package com.go.mycom.games.slots.server;

import com.go.games.slots.constant.GeneralConstants;
import com.go.games.slots.library.feature.IngLogHandler;
import com.go.games.slots.processor.SlotGameProcessor;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.net.ServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MycomServer {
    private static final String TLS_STRING_CONSTANT = "TLS";
    private static final String SUN_X_509_STRING_CONSTANT = "SunX509";
    private static final String JKS_STRING_CONSTANT = "JKS";
    private static final String CERT_FILE_NAME_STRING_CONSTANT = "cert.file.name";
    private static final String CERT_FILE_PASS_STRING_CONSTANT = "cert.file.pass";
    private static final String mycom_SERVER_PORT = "mycom.server.port";
    private static final Logger logger = IngLogHandler.getIngLogger(MycomServer.class.getName());
    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public MycomServer() {
    }

    public void runServer(Map<String, String> configData, SlotGameProcessor slotGameProcessor, Map<String, List<String>> requiredRngValues) {
        String cerFileName = GeneralConstants.EMPTY_STRING.getStringConstant();
        String certFilePass = GeneralConstants.EMPTY_STRING.getStringConstant();

        try {
            logger.debug("configData = " + configData);
            cerFileName = (String)configData.get("cert.file.name");
            certFilePass = (String)configData.get("cert.file.pass");
        } catch (Exception var14) {
            logger.debug(var14);
        }

        URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(cerFileName);

        try {
            logger.debug("going to get socket connection...");
            ServerSocketFactory ssf = this.getServerSocketFactory(url, certFilePass);
            if ($assertionsDisabled || ssf != null) {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = ssf.createServerSocket(Integer.parseInt((String)configData.get("mycom.server.port")));

                while(true) {
                    logger.debug("waiting for the client connection request ...");
                    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket)serverSocket.accept();
                    InputStream dis = sslSocket.getInputStream();
                    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
                    slotGameProcessor.getGameEngine().getGameState().getRngList().clear();
                    ClientHandler thread = new ClientHandler(dis, printWriter, slotGameProcessor, requiredRngValues, this.executorService);
                    this.executorService.execute(thread);
                    logger.debug("client thread has been started...");
                }
            }

            throw new AssertionError();
        } catch (Exception var13) {
            logger.debug("exception occurred in the connection .... " + var13);
        }
    }

    private ServerSocketFactory getServerSocketFactory(URL url, String certFilePass) {
        try {
            char[] passphrase = certFilePass.toCharArray();
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(url.openStream(), passphrase);
            kmf.init(ks, passphrase);
            ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), (TrustManager[])null, (SecureRandom)null);
            SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
            return ssf;
        } catch (Exception var8) {
            logger.debug("exception occurred during to get server socket factory" + var8);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code what I tried:

```
    package com.ingenuity.games.rgs;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String read = "{\"type\":\"INIT\",\"data\":{\"action\":\"init\"}}";
        try {

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:\\platform\\client.cert");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "weblogic");

            URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("client.jks");
            SSLSocketFactory factory = getServerSocketFactory(url, "weblogic");
            SSLSocket socketEngine = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("y.x.z.t", 6784);
            BufferedReader bufferedReaderEngine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketEngine.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter printWriterEngine = new PrintWriter(socketEngine.getOutputStream());
            printWriterEngine.println(read);
            printWriterEngine.println();
            printWriterEngine.flush();
            try {
                while ((read = bufferedReaderEngine.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("message received from engine..." + read);
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("exception = " + exception);
        }
    }

    private static SSLSocketFactory getServerSocketFactory(URL url, String certFilePass) {
        SSLSocketFactory ssf;
        try {
            char[] passphrase = certFilePass.toCharArray();
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(url.openStream(), passphrase);
            kmf.init(ks, passphrase);
            ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
            ssf = ctx.getSocketFactory();
            return ssf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This gives me following exception:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
```

Can anybody help me on this? What wrong is there?

Comment: Is `d:\platform\client.cert` simply a certificate, as the name suggests, or a keystore file _containing_ a certificate, as required for javax.net.ssl.trustStore? (In general it also needs to be the correct type, which since you didn't change it is your JVM's default, but for 8u60 up there is a compatibility feature that the usual default accepts either JKS or PKCS12 and in practice one of those is almost always used.) If that doesn't help set sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl,trustmanager` and look at the log to see what it's doing.